# [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]:Requires development platform R but this is a release platform

Tags: android

I have facing error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1664748577.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7): Requires development platform R but this is a release platform.

the manifest file email app has this defined

my build.gradle(:app) file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0-rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'R'
    }
    ...
}
```

Please help me to solve the issue .

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to API `R` beacuse it is still in preview use API `29` to release an APK

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement newer android sdk in my app, its fails at older versions like android 10 and low devices & its only works at android R device.

Comment: Previusly i have set the this configurations,
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
and its works for all devices.
After modified the SDK version to "R" getting failed.